# How to override the white background of an app that is displayed in Android Recent Apps list?

Tags: flutter

Where in the app does the white background in the Android Recent Apps list come from? This app is running in a dark theme, where this green is the `primary colour` (or maybe from another theme property). Accordingly, the white background on the screenshot should also come from somewhere in the theme - what theme property is responsible for this?

The following properties is not solving the issue

```
colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
    background: Colors.yellowAccent,
    onBackground: Colors.yellowAccent,
  ),
canvasColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
disabledColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
```

[image]

Comment: When in the app, you see taht white color too? are you using a scaffold? maybe in your theme change scaffoldBackgorund: Colors.black to see if it changes

Comment: @EdwynZN `scaffoldBackgroundColor` defines scaffold color and it doesn't work there

Comment: ok but how does it looks when youre inside the app? and what widget are you using there?